# React, por que utilizar props no constructor?

Tags: javascript, react

Por que eu devo usar `props` dentro do `constructor` e do `props`?

```
constructor(props){super(props)}
```

- Por que usar `props` no `constructor`?
- Por que usar `props` no `super`?
- Por que usar `super`?

Comment: Porque quando o elemento é renderizado, é criada uma instância dele, nessa instanciação é passado as propriedades (`new MyElement({propName: 'propValue'})`. O super serve para chamar o construtor da classe estendida, se faz isso porque o React realiza mais algumas coisas com essas propriedades

Comment: A passagem de props pela instancia é opcional. Pode ser usada se quiser fazer algo com elas no construtor. Se chamar construtor() {super()} à partida irá funcionar.

Comment: Mas quais seriam essas props que vem pelo constructor? tento dar um console.log nelas, mas não consigo

Comment: Este artigo escrito por um dos membros da equipe do React explica essa necessidade. [Leia-o arqui.](https://overreacted.io/pt-br/why-do-we-write-super-props/)

Comment: Tem um artigo muito bom do Dan Abramov(Um dos principais desenvolvedores do Redux e figura super relevante do React)sobre isso: https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/ Fica a dica inclusive de um ótimo nome para seguir para quem quer trabalhar com React.

Answer (score 6):

No React, quando se cria um componente statefull, deve se estender uma Classe Javascript Nativa, com o `React.Component` ficando:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Sendo assim a propriedade `props` pertence ao `React.Component`, e para acessar o conteúdo do `React.Component` na montagem da classe `Container`, deve se usar o `super` para injetar as propriedades (props, métodos) assim que o constructor for chamado.
Ficando deste modo:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      list: props.list
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Por isso a definição do MDN diz que:

A palavra-chave `super` é usada para acessar o objeto pai de um objeto, em outros casos, é usada para acessar a classe pai de uma classe.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Answer (score 2):

### Por que usar super?

A palavra-chave `super` é usada para acessar o objeto pai de um objeto, em outros casos, é usada para acessar a classe pai de uma classe.

Quando usada no construtor de uma classe, `super` deve ser usado apenas uma vez, e antes que a palavra-chave `this` possa ser usada.

### Por que usar props no constructor?

Só faz sentido utilizá-la no construtor se você quer inicializar o state baseado nas props. Ou se você quiser usar algum método passado via `props`.

Exemplo:

```js
class Pai extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Filho num={0} />
        <Filho num={10} />
        <Filho num={20} />
      </div>
    );
  };
}

class Filho extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();

    this.state = {
      num: props.num,
    };
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    const {num} = this.state;
    this.setState({ num: num + 1});
  };

  render() {
    const { num } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        num = {num}
        <button
          onClick={this.handleClick} 
        >
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

[Demo no codepen](https://codepen.io/rodamaral/pen/WLgraL)

### Por que usar props no super?

Você pode usar `super()` ou `super(props)`. A única diferença é que usar `super(props)` fará com que `this.props` seja idêntico a `props`.